# Extracting year from string in python

Tags: python, regex

How can I parse the foll. in python to extract the year:

```
'years since 1250-01-01 0:0:0'
```

The answer should be 1250

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are all sorts of ways to do it, here are several options:

- [`dateutil` parser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) in a "fuzzy" mode:

  ```
  In [1]: s = 'years since 1250-01-01 0:0:0'

  In [2]: from dateutil.parser import parse

  In [3]: parse(s, fuzzy=True).year  # resulting year would be an integer
  Out[3]: 1250
  ```
- regular expressions with a *capturing group*:

  ```
  In [2]: import re

  In [3]: re.search(r"years since (\d{4})", s).group(1)
  Out[3]: '1250'
  ```
- splitting by "since" and then by a dash:

  ```
  In [2]: s.split("since", 1)[1].split("-", 1)[0].strip()
  Out[2]: '1250'
  ```
- or may be even splitting by the first dash and slicing the first substring:

  ```
  In [2]: s.split("-", 1)[0][-4:]
  Out[2]: '1250'
  ```

The last two involve more "moving parts" and might not be applicable depending on possible variations of the input string.

Comment: Didn't know about "fuzzy".  Neat.

Comment: Neat! I didn't know about this one either.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a regex with a capture group around the four digits, while also making sure you have a particular pattern around it. I would probably look for something that:

- 4 digits and a capture `(\d{4})`
- hyphen `-`
- two digits `\d{2}`
- hyphen `-`
- two digits `\d{2}`

Giving: `(\d{4})-\d{2}-\d{2}`

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> d = re.findall('(\d{4})-\d{2}-\d{2}', 'years since 1250-01-01 0:0:0')
>>> d
['1250']
>>> d[0]
'1250'
```

if you need it as an int, just cast it as such:

```
>>> int(d[0])
1250
```

Comment: You don't need the \s in the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

The following regex should make the four digit year available as the first capture group:

```
^.*\(d{4})-\d{2}-\d{2}.*$
```