# How can I get the years from a string and put it into a separate list?

Tags: python

Code:

```
str1 = "2016-02-30T14:44:22.477Z, 2012-08-03T06:27:14.873Z, 2017-03-30T14:44:21.383Z"
```

I want only the years put into a separate list with output:
("2016", "2012", "2017")

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. What have you already tried, and where are you stuck? Are you familiar with `str.split()` or regex or the `datetime` library? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Use `str1.split(sep=',')` and then follow this link. Does this answer your question? [Extracting year from string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40121822/extracting-year-from-string-in-python)

Comment: What's up with February 30? That date doesn't exist.

Comment: @wjandrea I changed the dates just for this example  didn't even realise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions. You will first need to import the regular expressions module `import re` and then

```
years = re.findall(r'\d\d\d\d', str1)
```

The findall method will return every substring of str1 in which the regular expression is true. The `\d` character describes a digit.

`years` will be a list `['2016', '2012', '2017']`

Comment: You can simplify: `r'\d{4}'`

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 - Using split function

```
str1 = "2016-02-30T14:44:22.477Z, 2012-08-03T06:27:14.873Z, 2017-03-30T14:44:21.383Z"

years=[]
s = str1.split(",")

for i in s:
    years.append(i.split("-")[0])
    
print(years)
```

Method 2 - Using regex

```
str1 = "2016-02-30T14:44:22.477Z, 2012-08-03T06:27:14.873Z, 2017-03-30T14:44:21.383Z"

years = re.findall(r'\d{4}', str1)
```